# Skipping specific child from layout children that is matching given condition

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `LinearLayout` that is holding couple of `TextViews`- all together they have behaviour of `EditText`

There are 2 styles of `TextView` - one for actual digit and second for separator "-"

*LinearLayout with the views:*

[image]

Every time I put number in `EditText` the number is rendered in according position of `TextViews`

Want I want to achieve is like skipping the seperator view while rendering, so final result would be:

`1 2 3 4 - 5 6 7 8 -_ _ _ _`

*Layout:*

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerCodeDigits"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

*Digit view:*

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelManualCodeItem"
        style="@style/Gotham"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_24sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp"/>
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/business_color_1" />
```

*Separator view:*

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelManualCodeItem"
        style="@style/Gotham"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/manualcode_item_separator"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The code

```
var inputtedText: Editable = "".toEditable()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            renderCode()
        }

private val textChangedListener = object : TextWatcher {

//      every time digit is inserted renderCode() all views
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            inputtedText = s.toString().toEditable()
        }
}

private fun renderCode() {
    for (i in 0 until containerCodeDigits.childCount) {

//      itemContainer can be seperator view or normal digit view
        val itemContainer = containerCodeDigits.getChildAt(i)
        val itemTextView = itemContainer.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.labelManualCodeItem)

//      if current TextView is separator then skip it, 
//      but how to insert current digit to the next TextView after Seperator view is skipped
        if (itemTextView.text.toString() == "=") {
            continue
        }
//      put text to the TextView - is only applied to normal digit views
        itemTextView.text = if (inputtedText.length > i){
            inputtedText[i].toString()
        } else {
            ""
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: In order to move to the digit input after separator, user has to click twice, since key is being pressed also on separator position. So when 5 is pressed, then it kind of "reserved" for the separator position, but its not displayed - which is also undersired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun renderCode() {
    val pos = 0;
    for (i in 0 until containerCodeDigits.childCount) {

//      itemContainer can be seperator view or normal digit view
        val itemContainer = containerCodeDigits.getChildAt(i)
        val itemTextView = itemContainer.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.labelManualCodeItem)

//      if current TextView is separator then skip it, 
//      but how to insert current digit to the next TextView after Seperator view is skipped
        if (itemTextView.text.toString().equals("-")) {
            continue
        }
//      put text to the TextView - is only applied to normal digit views
        itemTextView.text = if (inputtedText.length > pos){
            inputtedText[pos].toString()
            pos++
        } else {
            ""
        }
    }
}
```

So only if you actually assign a number to a field, the next digit will be used for the next label

Comment: Actually you have to still pressed second time when edittext is on separator position, and since there are 2 separators the shift will be double on the second one